# What is the Chinese translation for "Monero"?

Tags: language

What is the Chinese translation for "Monero"? (in both simplified and traditional)

How has it been chosen?

Answer (score 1):

"monero" means "currency" in Esperanto, so traditional Chinese would be:
貨幣 (Huòbì)

Simplified Chinese would be:
货币 (Huòbì)